# Python: 404 Error when accessing page from localhost

Tags: python, flask, python-sockets

I had a situation right now that is currently impeding my progress on my work.

I am trying to use Flask and Sockets together so that I can check if a certain user is connected or not before I can show a video feed on the web browser.

Here is my code below.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from camera import VideoCamera, SocketConnections
import socket
import pickle
import struct
import new_client as NC #this is a client module

app = Flask(__name__)

video_camera = None
global_frame = None
urlfor_container = ""

HOST = ''
PORT = 5000


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print('Socket bind complete')
s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')
c = SocketConnections('127.0.0.1',5000)
c.Establish_Connection()

conn, addr = s.accept()
print('connected workstation ', addr)

data = b'' ### CHANGED
payload_size = struct.calcsize("L") ### CHANGED

# check if the connection was accepted
app.run(host='',threaded=True)
```

When I run this code, everything seems to be fine.

```
====== RESTART: C:\CENTRALIZED_SYSTEM_FILES\OpenCV Demozz\new_cam_serv.py ======
Socket created
Socket bind complete
Socket now listening
test message should print if code was accessed
connected
connected workstation  ('127.0.0.1', 59283)
* Serving Flask app "new_cam_serv" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
[31m   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.[0m
[2m   Use a production WSGI server instead.[0m
* Debug mode: off
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

However when I tried to access the webpage from localhost (localhost:5000/127.0.0.1:5000), I'm receiving a " 404 Page Not Found" error. I already have a templates folder along with the index.html inside the same folder where the main module is located but every time I run this code, I still receive the 404 message.

Also, I've tried using different variations for the IP address but no luck, still 404.

Any help from you guys will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: I've tried create an if **name**=="**main**" statement at the bottom and then inserted this code snippet inside the clause. Then I noticed that the flask server ran successfully and I was able to browse the page again, but here is the issue. after I interrupted the execution, then that is the only time my code for the socket connection got executed.

So my question now is... is it even possible for the socket and Flask to be used at the same time?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to provide an update that I have found a solution to this. It is indeed possible to use both socket and Flask at the same time.

I found out that the app.run() requires a valid IP address for it to work when used with socket. **The IP address from the socket and the IP address from Flask need to be the same IP address or else it won't work.** I found that out when I tried to debug my script and noticed that the socket and Flask on my script are referring to different IP addresses.

So, I changed:

```
app.run(host='',threaded=True)
```

to this:

```
app.run(host='127.0.0.1',threaded=True)
```

I've tried this with other IP addresses and it is working just fine.

Thank you again, everyone.